# Create a pdf file without using any 3rd party library in c?

Tags: c, pdf

My objective is to create a file and save some text in it. But the twist is that file should be created in pdf format without using any library.
I have written following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp; 
    char ch; 
    fp = fopen("file.pdf", "w"); 
    fprintf(fp, "%PDF-1.3"); //to initiate data storage in pdf file 
    printf("\nEnter data to be stored in to the file:"); 
    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF) 
        putc(ch,fp); 
    fclose(fp); 
    return 0;
}
```

Now my file is created in pdf format, but when I open it by double click on it, it is not open and gives the message like:
"Error in opening document. This file is damaged and could not be repaired."

Please provide any suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: file is file extension doesn't adds file-format and header infos., you have to create a file that according to PDF format. Use library

Comment: Disregarding the whole PDF-building, your program is still broken for what it attempts to do. `getchar()` returns `int`, since `EOF` does not fit in a character.

Comment: If you're really set on reinventing the wheel Adobe has made the [PDF specifications available](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html).

Comment: `"%PDF-1.3"` would produce undefined behaviour. If you want to print `%` character, then you should have `"%%PDF-1.3"`. `%%` will write a single `%` to the stream.

Answer (score 8):

Naming a file "file.pdf" and writing a couple of header bytes does not make it a PDF file. A file format is determined by its **content**, not its name (or the couple of bytes that certain tools like `file` use to "guess" the format).

If you want to write a PDF file "without using any library", you would need a description of the PDF file format, and then generate your file *according to that specification*.

I would *strongly* discourage this approach. Third-party libraries are there for a reason.

Comment: So the unix tool `file` can be tricked into recognizing a wrong file format?

Comment: @ajay: `man 5 magic`. That's the lookup that `file` uses. If a file looks sufficiently *like* a given format, `file` will identify as *being* that format. Any file beginning with "\x7fELF\x02\x01" will be recognized as "ELF 64-bit LSB", even if the rest is plain text. What should `file` do, *execute* the file to check if it's really an executable?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a file in a specific format without the help of any library, the first natural step should be looking at the *specification* of the format.

In case of PDF the specification is an ISO standard. Unlike most ISO standards, though, which you have to pay money for, you can download a free version from the Adobe web site which merely uses different headers and footers: [ISO 32000-1 copy from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

If you do not like the RFC'ish language of the ISO specification, you can alternatively look at the latest PDF references by Adobe themselves; in these documents alternative language mechanisms are used to specify requirements, recommendations, options, interdictions, etc.: [PDF reference, sixth edition (Version 1.7)](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf).